# Pull records ahead of time

Tags: sql, date

I'm trying to develop an 'upcoming listings' puller for my website, however the following query does not seem to be performing as it should.

The SQL:

`SELECT * FROM listings WHERE start_date > DATE_SUB( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH )`

Rather than pulling listings from 3 months ahead it pulls all listings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to work with 'future' records, you should use `DATE_ADD` instead:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM listings
 WHERE start_date 
       BETWEEN CURDATE() 
       AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH);
```

Note that `BETWEEN ... AND` clause is inclusive: in other words, you'll have records for `start_date` equal both to the current's one and the one exactly 3 months after. If that's not the desired outcome, just use separate two conditions:

```
 WHERE start_date > CURDATE() 
       AND start_date < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH);
```

As it stands now, you collect all the records having `start_date` set to *later* than 3 months *before* the current date. That probably includes the whole dataset.